# Proving basis functions span the rotation-invariant subspace of R3

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products, rotations, complete-spaces, invariance

What would be the correct way to prove a set of basis functions spans the rotation-invariant subspace of R3? I have a set of function that I know spans R3, and by combining the projection results in a specific way, I found a this combination to be rotation-invariant and I have a way to prove it. However, I'm not sure how to mathematically prove/show it's complete in the rotation-invariant subspace, or what criteria needs to be met to claim such completeness.

Maybe this is not the correct way to ask it, and we need to rephrase it somehow, but such basis of rotation-invariant subspace would have the same projection/representation for functions that are rotation transformations of each other, yet different for different functions.

Maybe we can rephrase it as: proving the completeness for functions in R3 but with their internal reference frame? But I'm not sure how to show that either... and I feel like this would involve some alignment issue.

Comment: I guess you're not talking about subspaces of the $3$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb R^3$. The only *vector* in $\mathbb R^3$ that is rotation-invariant is the zero vector $\mathbf0=(0,0,0)$. Rather, you're probably talking about subspaces of the infinite-dimensional Hilbert space of square-integrable *functions*, $L^2(\mathbb R^3)$. Right?

Comment: @ChrisCulter Thanks for your comment! I'm not very familiar with Hilbert space, but after a quick search I think it looks very much like the problem I'm trying to solve! Two quick questions if you could help me here: 1) it's a subspace of L2(R3) because of the "rotation invariance" property right? How should we define such subspace? 2) What would be the strategy to prove completeness for this subspace?

Comment: Well, although I can help to formulate the problem, I'm afraid I can't be of much help answering it. Everything I know about Hilbert spaces, I learned a long time ago, and in a non-rigorous setting. Sorry!